# Spyder: How can I debug parts of a python program without having to debug/execute the whole file?

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

Suppose I have two program parts: A and B. A comes before B. Part A is finished and tested. In part A, for example, large files are loaded, which can take a relatively long time. Part B is directly dependent on part A, because part B uses the data of part A. But part B is still under development, which makes frequent debugging necessary. If I set a breakpoint in part B, then I have to force part A to run every time so that the breakpoint in part B is reached. Isn't there a more elegant method, because the data that part A loads is already in the workspace in Spyder and therefore already available for part B? Can I debug part B separately, i.e. can I somehow get Spyder to execute only part B with its breakpoints?

```
# Part A with time-consuming functions (e.g. loading files). Tested and ready.
# ... some code here ...

# Here comes part B which is not ready yet and still under development with 
# breakpoints. 
# ... some code here ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly, I suggest two resolutions:

1. rewrite your code to a Jupyter notebook, allocating two (or more) blocks for each code segment
2. if you're using PyCharm, you can use the `#%%` syntax to divide your code to segmands, allowing you to run each segment separately

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You're suggesting two other IDE's, and even in those IDEs you are not giving a solution to what is being asked at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spyder has this capability with the "Debug cell" command (Alt+Shift+Return). You can find this command in the list of keyboard shortcuts when searching "debug".